# Ubuntu ZFS install hangs before reaching grub menu

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, grub

After upgrading some packages and restarting, I can no longer reach the grub menu. My system hangs at the motherboard logo and provides no other output.

I can boot to an Ubuntu Installer USB, and I can even get my ZFS pool mounted, but I’m hesitant to try any kind of grub repair since it sounds like that works a bit differently in ZFS world. I wouldn’t be quite sure where to start.

As an alternative, I’ve attempted using these instructions (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225751/recovering-a-borked-grub-with-a-ubuntu-19-10-zfs-root-filesystem) to use the Installer’s grub to boot my ZFS system but it fails:

`Begins Importing pool 'rpool' using defaults ... Failure 1`

I suspect “force” is needed since I imported it in the USB recovery environment but I can’t find how to provide that flag in grub.

I’m at a loss and would very much prefer not to rebuild my system. Does anyone have any suggestions on either of my approaches?

I am running Ubuntu 21 or 22… if I could get further in the boot process I would know for sure. Grub version on the installer is 2.04.

Comment: Unfortunately, booting from a ZFS pool is somewhat experimental. I can think that the issue is due to enabling some unsupported (by grub) pool property on `bpool` or `rpool`. This is the exact reason why I leave boot and root partition on classical filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to get the ZFS volume to mount and was forced to do a fresh install.

Comment: This means the drive would be faulty, just maybe.